# Makefile cannot find executable - no such file or directory

Tags: macos, makefile, path

I have a minimal makefile used in a flutter project:

```
run-profile:
    flutter run -t lib/main_dev.dart --profile
```

I run
`make run-profile` and get this error

```
flutter run -t lib/main_dev.dart --profile
make: flutter: No such file or directory
make: *** [run-profile] Error 1
```

I can run in same terminal totally fine the command `flutter` and get normal outputs etc

```
flutter 
Manage your Flutter app development.

Common commands:

  flutter create <output directory>
    Create a new Flutter project in the specified directory.

  flutter run [options]
    Run your Flutter application on an attached de
```

I even modified /etc/paths

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin


/Users/me/flutter/bin
```

and stil makefile cannot find flutter bin, or i have some syntax error in makefile.

I am on macos big sur 11.4

Comment: The shell that make uses (which is not the same as the one you use in your terminal) did not find the `flutter` executable. Try defining the `PATH` environment variable to include the right directory: `export PATH=$PATH:/some/where` and then `make...`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet how can i do that ? I have exported path for flutter in ~/.bash_profile ~/.bashrc also, and in /etc/paths as posted here

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. You could add some `@echo $(PATH)` and/or `@echo $(SHELL)` recipes to your Makefile to better understand what's going on.

Comment: In the end of my ~/.bashrc I have added this line `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/kristi.jorgji/flutter/bin/flutter"
` and that path i can execute if of flutter, also if i run `type flutter` that path is shown

Comment: `@echo $(SHELL)` result is `/bin/sh`

Comment: And what about `PATH`?

Comment: `/Users/kristi.jorgji/go/bin:/Users/kristi.jorgji/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/bin:/Users/kristi.jorgji/.tgenv/bin:/Users/kristi.jorgji/.sdkman/candidates/micronaut/current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/local/go/bin:~/flutter/bin:/Users/kristi.jorgji/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/kristi.jorgji/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/kristi.jorgji/flutter/bin/flutter:~/flutter/bin/flutter
`

Comment: It is crazy i see a lot of flutter in the path variable above...

Comment: Among them I see already added the flutter path `/Users/kristi.jorgji/flutter/bin/flutter`, just running this in terminal i get flutter executed, but makefile for some reason cannot find it

Comment: The `PATH` you show is really what was printed by a `@echo $(PATH)` recipe in your Makefile?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet yes correct, that is printed by makefile from commmand `@echo $(PATH)`

Comment: Well, this is a mystery to me, sorry. Could it be some crazy macOS Big Sur "security feature" that allows you to run your executable explicitly from the command line but forbids `make` to do it on your behalf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add it in `PATH` variable, the `path` where flutter is present  before so that it will always consider this path while searching first.
The step can be done inside  your `makefile` also in below way:

```
export PATH := /Users/kristi.jorgji/flutter/bin/flutter: $(PATH)
run-profile:
    flutter run -t lib/main_dev.dart --profile
```

Note : Ensure you have `flutter` executable present in the path that you mentioned
`/Users/kristi.jorgji/flutter/bin/flutter`
If flutter executable is present in `bin` directory of your mentioned path, then you need to give path till `/Users/kristi.jorgji/flutter/bin`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but still doesn't work which is very very weird... Executing in terminal `/Users/kristi.jorgji/flutter/bin/flutter` gives back flutter command properly. I added and modified my makefile like `export PATH := /Users/kristi.jorgji/flutter/bin/flutter: $(PATH)  run-profile:
 flutter run -t lib/main_dev.dart --profile` then still when i run `make run-profile` I see output `make: flutter: No such file or directory make: *** [run-profile] Error 1
`

Comment: Can it be some weird permission issue here ? I don't expect that, because in terminal executing the path flutter is executed, and i call makefile from same termina..

Comment: @KristiJorgji yes that should have worked. You can check permissions by going in the directory and typing ``ls -l`` and also check if PATH variable got the appeneded flutter path. ``echo $${PATH}`` in the makefile target

Comment: `kristi.jorgji$ ls -ln /Users/kristi.jorgji/flutter/bin/flutter
-rwxr-xr-x  1 1128577383  1222451753  2101 Jun 22 14:36 /Users/kristi.jorgji/flutter/bin/flutter`

Comment: `/Users/kristi.jorgji/go/bin:/Users/kristi.jorgji/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/bin:/Users/kristi.jorgji/.tgenv/bin:/Users/kristi.jorgji/.sdkman/candidates/micronaut/current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/local/go/bin:~/flutter/bin:/Users/kristi.jorgji/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/kristi.jorgji/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/kristi.jorgji/flutter/bin/flutter:~/flutter/bin/flutter `

Comment: The `PATH` should reference, well, path, not the filename. Assuming that `/Users/kristi.jorgji/flutter/bin/flutter` is an actual binary, the `PATH` should contain only `/Users/kristi.jorgji/flutter/bin` part.

Comment: @KristiJorgji : Can you out the ``PATH`` as ``/Users/kristi.jorgji/flutter/bin`` as mentioned in my answer

Comment: @Altaf solved! Issue was that exported path was containing full path to binary, not the directory the path... i

Comment: `/Users/kristi.jorgji/go/bin:/Users/kristi.jorgji/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/bin:/Users/kristi.jorgji/.tgenv/bin:/Users/kristi.jorgji/.sdkman/candidates/micronaut/current/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/local/go/bin:~/flutter/bin:/Users/kristi.jorgji/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/kristi.jorgji/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/kristi.jorgji/flutter/bin/flutter:~/flutter/bin/flutter `

Comment: path was like above wrong, `flutter/bin/flutter` instead of just `flutter/bin`. i accepted your answer that was the issue + had to make this change in ~/.bash_profile export as ~/.bashrc was not getting called at all in new mac version so paths are broken for older flutter install